# how to zip a large directory into multiple zip-files?

Tags: split, zip, output

I have a directory containing 69GiB worth of data, small files, big files and anything in between.

what i want to do is, zip this folder to many zip-files having a specific size (e.g. 5GiB).

I tried it with gzip but can't find any suitable solution.

Is there any way to do this with gzip? or is there a better solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think winzip might have a suitable solution to what you're looking for: 
[SplitZip files](http://kb.winzip.com/kb/entry/86/)

Comment: Thank you! This looks like the right thing for my case